# Show Client Source Without Allowing Them to Copy It

Tags: svn, github

I have a client that I need to show source code to for his project, but I don't want him to be able to download or copy it easily until I allow him to. Is there a way to upload the code to github or some other place and then have it show up in image format?

Comment: If he wants it, he will OCR the images.  You cannot do this.  As a client I would find this a bit silly.

Comment: He could OCR the images but the code is large so it will take a lot time. He just wants to see the quality of the code before he makes the last payment.

Comment: I hear imgur is popular for hosting images ...

Comment: I need something besides that though, since i want to upload an entire code source and ensure that it is read-only, potentially in image format